# Mecanim Animation in Unity

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, animator

[image]

I am facing a problem while playing a animation which is already playing at the moment.
e.g. I am currently working on boxing fighting game in which when I punch twice, first time animation is played but second time, it doesn't restart animation.
I also tried turning off that animation if it is already running, not finding any clue regarding this problem as I'm beginner in mecanim animation.

Comment: Could you maybe send (maybe as an image) what you tried?

Comment: an image of transitions of animator window or code???

Answer (score 0):

Mecanim doesn't allow you to do this directly. A state can only be in one *state* at a time. Either at the end and fading out or at the start and fading in, but not both at once.

You can do a hacky workaround where you make two states with the same animation and alternate between them each time you want to play that animation. It's annoying to set up and makes it take more effort if you need to refactor, but it does work.

My [Animancer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/animancer-lite-116516) plugin on the Unity Asset Store has a function specifically for this situation: CrossFadeNew will always fade the animation in from the beginning. If it's already playing it will automatically create a new state to fade in while the old one fades out. Feel free to contact me via the support email address listed on the store page and in the user manual if you have any questions about it.